# How would you reproduce the Leibniz binary table

Tags: longtable, arrays, marginpar, tabu, marginnote

I would like to reproduce the original Leibniz binary table (as seen [here](http://www.uqac.ca/flemieux/INF341/p85_89_vol3483m.pdf)).
The most precise the better...

[image: Leibniz original binary table]

Comment: 5 years later, her I am just for remembering this acronym that healthily many will ask you here: `please, provide a Minimal Working Example`. I feel guilty not giving back formatting tips  that only latex could provide. All the people I've interacted with here were nothing but helping and willing to give free educations so I'd like to say upfront: thank you. I've moved from academics, I don't really know what I'll do tomorrow. I once planed a style with helpful insights about the know-how of latex, but now, I'll just share this with you: https://framagit.org/haberman/latex-giveback

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can build up on this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\?}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize0}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc|r}
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 0 & 0 \\
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 \\
\cline{6-6}
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{5-6}
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
\cline{4-6}
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  8 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  9 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\
\cline{3-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're reproducing the text, it would make sense to use oldstyle numerals across it, so, for instance, `\usepackage[rm={oldstyle,tabular}]{cfr-lm}`. The `tabular` option makes all digits have the same width, as in the old document.

With some refinements for getting the double rule:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle,tabular}]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\?}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize0}}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc|@{}>{\,\vline\hspace{\tabcolsep}\hfill}r}
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 0 & 0 \\
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 \\
\cline{6-6}
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\cline{5-6}
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
\cline{4-6}
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  8 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  9 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\
\cline{3-6}
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 17 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 18 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 19 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 21 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 22 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 23 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 25 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 26 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 27 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 28 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 29 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 30 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 31 \\
\cline{2-6}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\ \&c.} &\hfill \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to place the table at the same height as the page header, you should postpone the task when you *know* where the table should be placed. Then you can add the table with a `\marginpar` in the first line of the page. Here's a simulation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[rm={oldstyle,tabular}]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\setlength{\marginparsep}{3pt}

\newcommand{\?}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize0}}

\newcommand{\raisetohead}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\headsep+\topskip\relax}[0pt]{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\tabledenombres}{%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cccccc|@{}>{\,\vline\hspace{\tabcolsep}\hfill}r}
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{TABLE}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\scshape de}\\
  \multicolumn{7}{c}{\scshape Nombres}\\
  \? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 0 & 0 \\
  \? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 \\
  \cline{6-6}
  \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
  \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
  \cline{5-6}
  \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
  \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
  \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
  \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
  \cline{4-6}
  \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  8 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  9 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\
  \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\
  \cline{3-6}
  \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 17 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 18 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 19 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 21 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 22 \\
  \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 23 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 25 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 26 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 27 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 28 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 29 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 30 \\
  \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 31 \\
  \cline{2-6}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\
  \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\ \&c.} &\hfill \\
  \end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Numbers}

\clearpage % simulate being at a new page

XYZ\marginpar[% this is the first word in the first line of the page
  \hfill\raisetohead{\tabledenombres}%
]{%
  \raisetohead{\tabledenombres}%
}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest using ebgaramond which has old style tabular numbers, and a more traditional-looking old style `1`?

Comment: @Bernard That's a possibility; there are several fonts sporting ancient looking figures.

Comment: @Bernard Latin Modern also has tabular oldstyle numerals. (But the 1 is the 1 is the 1, of course.) If you are just going to say `oldstyle`, you don't actually need to specify it as you'll get that anyway. But you need to say if you want tabular oldstyle rather than proportional as the latter are default.

Comment: `rm={oldstyle,tabular}`. Though you might not want this for the entire document. If not, you can use one of the switches to change the numerals for the table.

Comment: What if I want to insert that in a `marginpar`? While using a `longtable` is not working, would it be possible to force the content to be typeset at the top?

Comment: @nadous `longtable` can't do in a `\marginpar`; you have to set the `\marginpar` as high as possible, possibly raising and “smashing” the `tabular`.

Comment: @nadous I have added a possible trick. As I explain, getting this automatically is out of the question, unless you use packages that are able to place things in a fixed position.

Answer (score 5):

As simple table and with old style nums and the tricky double line, which is implemented by an additional column to prevent `\cline` from cutting through:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\Z}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\circ$}}
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{.5\tabcolsep}
  \oldstylenums{%
    \begin{tabular}{*{6}{c}@{\kern\tabcolsep}c@{}||r}
      \Z &\Z &\Z &\Z &\Z & 0 &&  0 \\
      \Z &\Z &\Z &\Z &\Z & 1 &&  1 \\
      \cline{6-6}
      \Z &\Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 0 &&  2 \\
      \Z &\Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 1 &&  3 \\
      \cline{5-6}
      \Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 0 &&  4 \\
      \Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 1 &&  5 \\
      \Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 0 &&  6 \\
      \Z &\Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 1 &&  7 \\
      \cline{4-6}
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &&  8 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &&  9 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 && 10 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 && 11 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 && 12 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 && 13 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 && 14 \\
      \Z &\Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 && 15 \\
      \cline{3-6}
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 && 16 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 && 17 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 && 18 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 && 19 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 && 20 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 && 21 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 && 22 \\
      \Z & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 && 23 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 && 24 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 && 25 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 && 26 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 && 27 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 && 28 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 && 29 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 && 30 \\
      \Z & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 && 31 \\
      \cline{1-6}
       1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 && 32 \\
      \multicolumn{6}{c}{\normalfont\&c.} && \\
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Packing this all up inside a `marginpar`. Not really convenient since you have to manually play with an additional `vspace` value.

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR

\documentclass[11pt, frenchb, twoside]{report}

% IMPORTS
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
             Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand{\?}{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\scriptsize0}}
% % % % % % % % LIG % % % % % % % %
% #1 optional fontsize (default: 10)
% #2 optional line (default: 11)
% #3 content
\ProvideDocumentCommand \lig{ O{10} O{11} m }
{
    \fontsize{#1}{#2}\fontspec[Alternate=1,Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Hoefler Text}\selectfont#3}

% % % % % % % % LEIBNIZBINARY % % % % % % % %
\ProvideDocumentCommand \leibnizBinary{}
{
    \vspace{-1in}
    {\Large \lig[20][20]{\textsc{Table des Nombres}} \lig[12][12]{de \textit{Leibniz}.}}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{.85}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \fontsize{10}{11}
    \begin{tabu} to \marginparwidth {X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]X[c]|@{}>{\,\vline\hspace{\tabcolsep}\hfill}r}
        \? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 0 & 0 \\
        \? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 \\
        \cline{6-6}
        \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 2 \\
        \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
        \cline{5-6}
        \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
        \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
        \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
        \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
        \cline{4-6}
        \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  8 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  9 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\
        \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\
        \cline{3-6}
        \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 17 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 18 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 19 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 21 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 22 \\
        \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 23 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 25 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 26 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 27 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 28 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 29 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 30 \\
        \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 31 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32 \\
        \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\ \&c.} &\hfill \\
    \end{tabu}}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[5]
    \marginpar[\raggedleft \leibnizBinary]
          {\raggedright \leibnizBinary}
    \blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

It also make benefits of the [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package so the binary table fills the `marginpar` width (or any size you want):

[image: Leibniz binary table reproduced]

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, an attempt to reproduce as faithfully as possible with `ebgaramond` for the tables. As this font doesn't seem to have historic `s` nor rare ligatures, I had to use a commercial font for the text that matches ebgaramond (Sabon Next LT Pro). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a5paper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond}
%\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{geometry}

%\geometry{textwidth =13.3cm,textheight = 21.3cm, nofoot, marginratio={4:6,5:7}}
\geometry{textwidth =9.9cm,textheight = 16.5cm, nofoot, marginratio={4:6,5:7},headsep = \baselineskip}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{myplain}{%
\sethead[\thepage\quad \scshape\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=12.0}Memoires de l’Academie Royale][][]%
{}{des Sciences}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{myplain}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=12.0,Numbers=Monospaced}}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{nolabel}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=15.0}#3}%{\lsstyle#3}
\usepackage{array, booktabs,wrapfig}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\newcommand{\?}{\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\scriptsize0}}
\newcommand\mystrut[1][3ex]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}
\newcommand{\textcdot}{\textperiodcentered}
\providecommand\slashed[1]{$\not\!\text{#1}$}

\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers = {OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures = Rare, Style = Historic, StylisticSet={1,5},WordSpace = 1.12}%
\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\setlength\aboverulesep{0.4pt}\setlength\belowrulesep{0.4pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.5pt}\setlength\cmidrulewidth{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{86}
\begin{wraptable}{l}[24mm]{20mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}\setlength\cmidrulekern{0.67pt}
\fontspec{EB Garamond 12 Regular}
\captionsetup{format=nolabel, justification=centering, font=sc, skip=0.5ex}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
%\setmainfont{EBGaramond12-Regular.otf}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{TABLE\\{\small des}\\Nombres.}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc|@{}>{\,\vline\hspace{\tabcolsep}\hfill}r}
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & \smash{0} & \smash{0}\\
\? & \? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 \\
\cmidrule(lr){6-6}
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 2\mystrut \\
\? & \? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\cmidrule(lr){5-6}
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6 \\
\? & \? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-6}
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 8\mystrut \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 10 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & \? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 11 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 12 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 14 \\
\? & \? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15 \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6}
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 16\mystrut \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 17 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 18 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 19 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 20 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 21 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 22 \\
\? & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 23 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 24 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 25 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 26 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 27 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 28 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 29 \\
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 30 \\
\midrule[0pt]
\? & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 31 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-6}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 32\mystrut \\
\multicolumn{6}{c|}{\&c.} &\hfill \\
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{wraptable}
%%
\vspace*{-3.64\baselineskip}%{-64.5pt}
\mbox{}

\vspace{1.33\baselineskip}

\noindent
bres entiers au-dessous du double du plus haut degré. Car ici, c’est comme si on disoit, par exemple, que 1\,1\,1 ou 7 est la somme de quatre, de deux \& d’un. Et que 1\,1\,0\,1 ou 1\,3 est la somme de huit, quatre \& un. Cette propriété sert aux Essayeurs pour peser toutes sortes de masses avec peu de poids, \& pourroit servir dans les monnoyes pour donner plusieurs avec peu de piéces.

Cette expression des Nombres étant établie, sert à faire très-facilement toutes sortes d’opérations.\medskip

\begin{raggedright}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}\setlength\doublerulesep{1.2pt}
\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=12.0}
\parbox{3.5cm}{%
Pour l’\emph{Addition}\\
par exemple.
}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cccc||r}
 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 6\\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7\\
\textcdot &\textcdot & & & \mbox{}\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 13
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
  & & 1 & 0&1 & 5\\
 & 1 & 0& 1 & 1& 11\\
\textcdot & \textcdot &\textcdot &\textcdot & & \mbox{}\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 16
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
  &1 & 1 &1&0 & 14\\
1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1& 17\\
\textcdot & \textcdot &\textcdot &\textcdot & & \mbox{}\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
1 & 1& 1 & 1 & 1& 31
\end{tabular}\\\bigskip
%%%%
\parbox{3.5cm}{%
Pour la \textit{Soustrac\- tion}.
}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cccc||r}
 1& 1 & 0 &1 & 13\\
  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 7\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 16
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
1 & 0& 0& 0& 0& 16\\
 & 1 & 0& 1 & 1& 11\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
  & & 1 & 0 & 1& 5
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
1 &1 & 1 &1& 1& 31\\
1 & 0 & 0& 0 & 1& 17\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
 & 1& 1 & 1 & 0& 14
\end{tabular}\\\bigskip
%%%%
\parbox{3.2cm}{%
Pour la \textit{Multi\-plication}.
}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{cccc||r}
  & & 1 &1 &\hphantom{0} 3\\
 & 1 & 1 & & 3\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
 & & 1 & 1 & \\
 & 1& 1 & & \\
 & \textcdot & & \\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 9
\end{tabular}
\raisebox{0.667\baselineskip}{\clap{$\odot$}}\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
  & & 1 & 0& 1 & 5\\
  & & & 1 & 1 &3\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
 & & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
   & 1 &0& 1 & & \\
 & & & & \\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-4}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){5-5}
\hphantom{1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 15
\end{tabular}
\quad
\begin{tabular}{ccccc||r}
 & & 1 & 0& 1 & 5\\
    & & 1 & 0 & 1 & 5\\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
 & & 1 & 0 & 1 & \\
  1 &0& 1 & 0 & & \\
  & & & & \\
\cmidrule(r{0.3em}){1-5}\cmidrule(l{0.1em}r){6-6}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 25
\end{tabular}\\
\bigskip
\parbox{3.2cm}{%
Pour la \textit{Division}.
}%
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{r||>{\scriptsize}l>{\scriptsize}l@{$ \! $}cc}
15 & \slashed{1} & \slashed{1} &1 &1\\
3 & \slashed{1} & \slashed{1} \slashed{1} & & 1\\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & & 1& 1 &
\end{tabular}
\quad \makebox[3pt]{\raisebox{-0.333\height}{\scalebox{1.25}[4]{\itshape\large s}}}
\begin{tabular}{ccc||r}
 1 & 0 & 1 & \hphantom{1}5\\
 & & &
\end{tabular}\\
\end{raggedright}
\bigskip
\noindent Et toutes ces opérations sont si aisées, qu’on n’a jamais besoin de rien essayer ni deviner, comme il faut faire dans la division ordinaire. On n’a point besoin non plus de rien apprendre par cœur ici, comme il faut faire dans le calcul ordinaire, où il faut sçavoir, par exemple, que 3 \& 7 pris ensemble font 13 ; \& que 5 multiplié par 3 donne 15,suivant la Table d’\emph{une fois un est un} ; qu’on appelle Pythagorique. Mais ici tout cela se trouve \& se prouve de source, comme l’on voit dans les exemples précédens sous les signes \& $ \odot $.


\end{document}
```

[image]